# db内の情報を検索し、検索したデータをそのまま反映させる方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

db内に情報が存在する or しないかの判別を行う検索フォームを作成しています。
検索フォームに入力するのは、メールアドレスのみです。
情報が存在していない場合、検索に使用したメールアドレスをそのまま、登録フォームに自動で反映させたいのですが、やり方がわからないです。
やり方を教えていただけないでしょうか？　コードは下記のようになっています。

> controller

```
  def searching
    @user = User.find_by(users_email: params[:user][:users_email])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user == nil
        format.html
        format.js { @status = "false" }
        @user = User.new
      else
        format.html
        format.js { @status = "success" }
        @entry = @user.entries.new
      end
    end
  end
```

> view 検索フォーム

```
.container-fluid.search-fruid
  = form_for(:user, action: 'searching', url: user_search_path, remote: true) do |f|
    = f.label :"メールアドレスを入力してください"
    = f.email_field :users_email, class: 'form-control'
    = f.submit "検索", class: 'btn btn-primary'
    = link_to "戻る", :back, :class => 'btn btn-default'


  %ul#searching
```

> view 情報がなかった時の登録フォーム

```
= simple_form_for @user, :url => {:action => 'user_regist' , method: "get"}, remote: true do |f|
    .form-group
      .col-lg-10
        = f.input :users_name, label: "名前"
    .form-group
      .col-lg-10
        = f.input :users_tel, label: "電話番号"
    .form-group
      .col-lg-10
        = f.input :users_email, label: "メールアドレス"
    .form-group
      .col-lg-10
        = f.input :users_zip_code, label: "郵便番号"
    .form-group
      .col-lg-10
        =f.label "都道府県"
        = f.select :users_pref_name, User.pref_name
    .form-group
      .col-lg-10
        = f.input :users_address, label: "住所"
    .form-group
      = f.button :submit, value:"登録", :class => 'btn-primary'
    = link_to '戻る', user_path, :class => 'btn btn-default'
```

このフォームのメールアドレスの箇所を入力されてある状態にしたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

回答と直接の関係はありませんが、
`params`を直接使うのではなく、Strong Parametersを使いましょう。

DBに存在しない場合は、コントローラでStrong ParametersからEmailを`@email`といったようなインスタンス変数に取り出して、View側に持っていけばよいだけのように思います。

simple_formは使ったことがありませんが、
`f.input :users_email, input_html: { value: @email }`
で値を入れれるのではないでしょうか。

もしくは
`@user = User.new(users_email: DBに存在しなかったEmail)`
`f.input :users_email, input_html: { value: @user.users_email }`
の方法でもよいでしょう。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。strong parametersからインスタンス変数を取りだし、viewに   ' f.input :users_email, input_html: { value:　} '                          を書いたら、うまく取り出すことができました。ご親切な解答ありがとうございました。

Comment: @katyou 解決した場合は、回答にチェックをお願いします。チェックをしないと未解決として残ってしまいます。チェックを入れると質問者の信用度も高まります。

Comment: チェック入れています。ご指摘ありがとうございます！